# If Statement Causes 'Use of Unresolved Identifier' for Returned Tuple

Tags: swift

The Swift (2) function show below returns a tuple containing two UIAlertAction instances cancelAction and doNotCancelAction. Prior to setting up the If statement code block the instances were returned as expected.

After adding the conditional if code block that includes the creation of the two UIAlertAction instances, the two entries in the returned tuple are now tagged by Xcode 7.0.1 as unresolved identifier errors.

Not sure why inserting the instance assignments in an if code block would cause this error.

Is there something about defining the tuple in the func declaration and then trying to assign to it in an if code block that would cause this error?

Can anyone help me understand what I'd doing incorrectly here.

Here's the code snippet:

```
struct UserInputValidation {
  static var textHasChanged = false
  static var editMode: EditMode?

//  ...

private static func setActions(segueName: String, controller:   UITableViewController) -> (cancelAction: UIAlertAction, doNotCancelAction: UIAlertAction)
{

  if (segueName == "exitToEntityTopicsListingTableViewController")
  {
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) in
    controller.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: controller)
    self.textHasChanged = false
    }
    let doNotCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action) in
    }
}
return (cancelAction, doNotCancelAction)
```

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

In your return statement you return a value that might not have been instantiated. So if the segue name is not "exitToEntityTopicsListingTableViewController" then there won't exist any `cancelAction` and `doNotCancelAction` to return.

You either have to move the return statement in to the if block as well or instantiate a default value for `cancelAction` and `doNotCancelAction`

Answer (score 0):

This error msg was caused by a failure to realize a basic concept was not being followed in that any var or constant created within a block is local to the block and can't be resolved when used outside of the block.

Solution was to move the declaration of the two constants outside of the if block into the func block.

Also, had to change from a constant to a var as I could not pre-assign the constants now that they were no longer in the if block.

So code now looks like:

```
private static func setActions(segueName: String, controller: EditTopicAndContentTableViewController) -> (cancelAction: UIAlertAction, doNotCancelAction: UIAlertAction)
{

  var cancelAction: UIAlertAction!
  var doNotCancelAction: UIAlertAction!

// User exits topic and content edit page with unsaved changes - yes   continues exit.
  if (segueName == "exitToEntityTopicsListingTableViewController")
  {
    cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) in
      controller.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: controller)
      self.textHasChanged = false
    }
    doNotCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default) { (action) in
    }
  }
// User accesses edit keywords page with unsaved changes which keywords edit needs changes to be saved.
// Yes is save changes and continue to keywords edit page.
  else if (segueName == "editKeywords")
  {
    cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action) in
    }
    doNotCancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action) in
        controller.saveTopicAndContentToCoreData(controller.coreDataStack)
      self.textHasChanged = false
      controller.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: controller)
    }
  }

  return (cancelAction, doNotCancelAction)
}
```